# Does QThread::quit() immediately end the thread or does it wait until returning to the event loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

There are a lot of Qt multi-threading tutorials out there that state that a `QThread` can be stopped safely using the following two lines.

```
qthread.quit(); // Cause the thread to cease.
qthread.wait(); // Wait until the thread actually stops to synchronize.
```

I have a lot of code doing this, and in most cases of stopping thread, I'll always set my own cancel flag and check it often during execution (as is the norm).  Until now, I was thinking that calling quit would perhaps cause the thread to simply no longer execute any waiting signals (e.g. signals that are queued will no longer have their slots called) but still wait on the currently executing slot to finish.

But I'm wondering if I was right or if `quit()` actually stops the execution of the thread where it's at, for instance if something is unfinished, like a file descriptor hasn't been closed, it definitely should be, even though in most cases my worker objects will clean up those resources, I'd feel better if I knew exactly how quit works.

I'm asking this because `QThread::quit()` documentation says that it's "equivalent to calling QThread::exit(0)".  I believe this means that the thread would immediately stop where it's at.  But what would happen to the stackframe that quit was called in?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`QThread::quit` does nothing if the thread does not have an event loop or some code in the thread is blocking the event loop. So it will not necessarily stop the thread.

So `QThread::quit` tells the thread's event loop to exit. After calling it the thread will get finished as soon as the control returns to the event loop of the thread.

You will have to add some kind of abort flag if you are blocking event loop for example by working in a loop. This can be done by a boolean member variable that is public or at least has a public setter method. Then you can tell the thread to exit ASAP from outside (e.g. from your main thread) by setting the abort flag. Of course this will require your thread code to check the abort flag at regular intervals.

You may also force a thread to terminate right now via [`QThread::terminate()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate), but this is a very bad practice, because it may terminate the thread at an undefined position in its code, which means you may end up with resources never getting freed up and other nasty stuff. So use this only if you really can't get around it. From its documentation:

> **Warning**: This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The thread can be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be terminated while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to clean up after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use this function only if absolutely necessary.

I think this is a good way to finish a thread when you are using loops in a thread:

```
myThread->m_abort = true; //Tell the thread to abort
if(!myThread->wait(5000)) //Wait until it actually has terminated (max. 5 sec)
{
  myThread->terminate(); //Thread didn't exit in time, probably deadlocked, terminate it!
  myThread->wait(); //We have to wait again here!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes I always use cancel (abort) flags in my threads regardless of whether or not they're simply running their own processing loop.  I was just curious regarding cases of using quit() when it comes to QThreads that are running the Qt event loop.

Comment: You can also override `myThread`'s class' `terminate();` slot (`virtual void terminate();`), so you can rollback what you've done just like you want. Just think to call `QThread::terminate();` at the end of your own `terminate();`. ;-)

Comment: Hi I am using PyQt but was interested in QThread.quit() and QThread.wait() any clues about why wait() goes after quit ?

Answer (score 3):

In case, if you want to use Qt's builtin facility then try [`QThread::requestInterruption()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#requestInterruption).

#### Main thread

```
struct X {
  QThread m_Thread; 
  void Quit ()
  {
    m_Thread.quit();
    m_Thread.requestInterruption();
  }
};
```

#### Some Thread referred by `X::m_Thread`

```
while(<condition>) {
  if(QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested())
    return;
  ...
}
```

As per the documentation:

> #### void QThread::requestInterruption()
>
> Request the interruption of the thread. That request is advisory and it is up to code running on the thread to decide if and how it should act upon such request. This function does not stop any event loop running on the thread and does not terminate it in any way.