# How to properly terminate QThread in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread, terminate

Is this a correct way  terminate the thread ...

```
 if(m_ReviewImageThreadLoader !=NULL)
 {
   m_ReviewImageThreadLoader->quit();
   m_ReviewImageThreadLoader->wait();
   m_ReviewImageThreadLoader->terminate();
   delete m_ReviewImageThreadLoader;
   m_ReviewImageThreadLoader = NULL;
   qDebug()<<"m_ReviewImageThreadLoader closed"<<endl;
 }
```

... where `m_ReviewImageThreadLoader` is the thread object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does QThread::quit() immediately end the thread or does it wait until returning to the event loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923354/does-qthreadquit-immediately-end-the-thread-or-does-it-wait-until-returning)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends to a large extent on the nature of the work being done on your thread.  If the usage is something like...

```
QThread *m_ReviewImageThreadLoader = new QThread;
MyObject *mo = new MyObject;
mo->moveToThread(m_ReviewImageThreadLoader);
m_ReviewImageThreadLoader->start();
```

then your code should be fine (although you really shouldn't need the call to `terminate()`).

If, on the other hand, `m_ReviewImageThreadLoader` is of a type derived from `QThread` and has explicitly overridden `QThread::run` then you'll need to supply more information before your question can be answered.

Have you tried your code?  Does it appear to work?

Comment: Hi GM , Thanks for u r reply , I have created  my object  like : m_ReviewImageThreadLoader = new ReviewImageThreadLoader(); m_ReviewImageThreadLoader  is its self inherited by Qthread and  m_ReviewImageThreadLoader  , no need to create new class  for that .. if u r using thread like that , now I want delete thread. I am asking for process for delete the thread. in this case this code will work fine

Comment: if(m_ReviewImageThreadLoader !=NULL)
 {
 m_ReviewImageThreadLoader->quit();
 m_ReviewImageThreadLoader->terminate();
 delete m_ReviewImageThreadLoader;
 m_ReviewImageThreadLoader = NULL;
 qDebug()<<"m_ReviewImageThreadLoader closed"<<endl;
 }